# Can't explore some directories on remote host with PhpStorm 2016

Tags: phpstorm

I configured a remote host on PhpStorm 2016 but I can't explore some directories and can't download those directories to my local project.

Somebody knows how I can resolve this trouble?

[image]

This is a picture taken from another editor, as you can see, I opened directories that are showed as not available on phpstorm2016

[image: Picture taken from another editor]

Comment: Show your deployment settings (all tabs) -- how did you configure your deployment entry. So far it could be not enough rights. Also: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Troubleshooting+Deployments+in+PhpStorm

Comment: I can't add more pictures for my reputation, but on Connection Tab, I configured a basic ftp connection. On Mappings Tab, where says "Deployment path on server" I just put a backslash "/". Finally on Excluded paths. There's a message says: Nothing to show. Thanks for your help

Comment: Collect logs ( https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Troubleshooting+Deployments+in+PhpStorm#TroubleshootingDeploymentsinPhpStorm-Howtocollectdeploymentlogsandprovidethemtooursupportengineers? ) and submit them together with the next support ticket at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new Right now all I see is that all subfolders are excluded or inaccessible for some reason.